# Access violation error on stereolabs

Tags: opencv, c++14

I'm writing a program to convert an image sensed with a StereoLabs ZED stereocamera to an OpenCV image, to do some processing, here is the code (including the setup part een if I don't know if the problem can be there):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sl/camera.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace sl;

cv::Mat zed_to_ocv(sl::Mat zed_mat) {

    int cv_type = -1;

    switch (zed_mat.getDataType()) {
        case MAT_TYPE_32F_C1: cv_type = CV_32FC1; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_32F_C2: cv_type = CV_32FC2; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_32F_C3: cv_type = CV_32FC3; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_32F_C4: cv_type = CV_32FC4; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_8U_C1: cv_type = CV_8UC1; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_8U_C2: cv_type = CV_8UC2; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_8U_C3: cv_type = CV_8UC3; break;
        case MAT_TYPE_8U_C4: cv_type = CV_8UC4; break;
        default: break;
    }

    return cv::Mat(zed_mat.getHeight(), zed_mat.getWidth(), cv_type, zed_mat.getPtr<sl::uchar1>(MEM_CPU));

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    InitParameters parameters;
    parameters.depth_mode = DEPTH_MODE_PERFORMANCE;
    parameters.coordinate_units = UNIT_METER;
    parameters.camera_fps = 30;
    if (argc > 1) {
        parameters.svo_input_filename = argv[1];
    }
    sl::Camera zed;

    ERROR_CODE err = zed.open(parameters);
    if (err != SUCCESS) {
        zed.close();
        cout << "Error while opening ZED camera";
        return -1;
    }

    RuntimeParameters runtime_parameters;
    runtime_parameters.sensing_mode = SENSING_MODE_STANDARD;

    Resolution image_size = zed.getResolution();
    int new_width = image_size.width;
    int new_height = image_size.height;

    sl::Mat image_zed(new_width, new_height, MAT_TYPE_8U_C4);
    cv::Mat image_ocv = zed_to_ocv(image_zed);
    cv::Mat image(new_width, new_height, CV_8UC1);

    while (true) {
        if (zed.grab(runtime_parameters) == SUCCESS) {
            zed.retrieveImage(image_zed, VIEW_LEFT, MEM_CPU, new_width, new_height);

            cv::cvtColor(image_ocv, image, CV_BGRA2GRAY);

            imshow("camera", image);
            waitKey(30);
        }
    }

    zed.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works just fine, but if I wanted to use 32F matrices instead (changing the type of both *image_zed* and *image*) I get a

```
Exception in correspondence of 0x00007FF97D175400 (opencv_imgproc340d.dll) in projectCV.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation error reading 0x000002C52DC13040.
```

error. I tried changing to

```
getPtr<sl::float1>
```

inside *zed_to_ocv*, but the error is still there.

EDIT: Debugging I found out the crash happens at line

```
cv::cvtColor(image_ocv, image, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
```

but I still can't figure out why.

What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: You should debug your program to find out which line causes crash.

Comment: You're right, I just did and I found out the problem is at the line with the cv::cvtColor() instruction